# Color of text changed when font changed in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, fonts, colors, richtextbox

I use RichTextBox in my windows application program. The rtf of RichTextBox has text with any color. I use Combobox for user can change font of RichTextBox. My problem is when user change font, all text of RichTextBox has black.
How can i privent to change color of text ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use the .SelectionFont-Property of the RichTextBox

more infos:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont.aspx